# HttpResponse returns a 502 Error, doesn't appear to hit endpoint

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application that uses HttpResponse for network calls.

Occasionally (about 30% of the time) network calls seem to fail with a 502 returning from the server. When checking the server logs, It appears that the server never received the request.

The logic doesn't seem bad, however, and it does work most of the time. I am communicating to the server via JSON.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost method = new HttpPost( BASE_URL + endpoint )
...add json entity
method.addHeader( "content-type", "application/json" );
        method.addHeader( "accept", "application/json" );
```

....call below function w client/method

```
protected HttpResponse invoke( HttpClient client, HttpUriRequest method ) throws ServiceException {

    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        response = client.execute( method );
    } catch ( //catch statements here ....)

    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    //status = 502
}
```

The interesting thing about this call failing is that it's the exact same call across devices, and the server it's hitting is 20 feet away, although it does happen on a different server located in another state.

I can't see why it works sometimes but not others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run wire shark on both sender and receiver . Observe sends and receives. You should be able to see the cause of the problem.

If you are getting a 502 error it suggests an intermediate device ( proxy,web filter,etc ) is blocking or " eating " your HTTP post .

Comment: Running wireshark, I was able to see that the server is sending a 502 back. Thanks for the idea, looks like I have bigger problems now :/

Comment: Ok so the 502 is coming from your server , so what does the web server log say for that request ?  Watch the incoming request in wireshark and check all its elements ( ie headers and content ) for an explaination. I have seen switches mangle headers . Also you might try directly connecting your Dev box to your server ( to rule out any intermediate problems )

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say it, but this just sounds like an infrastructure issue. Some networking problem between your device, and the server. The code itself looks fine